# input values are inline, not separated by line breaks

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm a reactJS newbie and I'm practising by creating a simple example that the expected result is, each input value (separated by whitespace) inserted in an HTML element (`<h1>`). What it executed instead is each output value disappears when it's being separated by space. It's much better to copy-paste the code below on your own project to understand exactly what I mean.

```
import React from 'react';

class Items extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      result: ''
    }

    this.showItems = this.showItems.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    let results = this.state.result,
        resultItem = [];

    for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
      resultItem = results[i];
    }

    return(
      <div>

        /* Example, the user typed "Item1 Item2 Item3" */
        <input type='text' placeholder='Enter items' onChange={this.showItems} />

        <div className='result'>
          <h1>{resultItem}</h1>
          /*
            Here, the displayed result should be:

            <h1>Item1</h1>
            <h1>Item2</h1>
            <h1>Item3</h1>
          */
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }

  itemsResult(result) {
    this.setState({result});
  }

  showItems(e) {
    const items = e.target.value.split(' ');
    this.itemsResult(items);
  }
}

export default Items;
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map over the array that you create after splitting by `space`

```js
class Items extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      result: []
    }

    this.showItems = this.showItems.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
   
    return(
      <div>

        
        <input type='text' placeholder='Enter items' onChange={this.showItems} />

        <div className='result'>
          {this.state.result.length > 0 && this.state.result.map(function(item , index){
           return <h1 key={index}>{item}</h1>
          })}
          
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }

  itemsResult (result) {
  console.log(result)
    this.setState({result});
  }

  showItems(e) {
    const items = e.target.value.split(' ');
    this.itemsResult(items);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Items/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Shubham, You missed KEY attribute in <h1>

Comment: @Ved You can update your answer with some little more explanation

Comment: I updated. And more thing, always use this.state.result.length>0 instead of just this.state.result. It is good practice

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I just have one question, why is `map()` more preferable than `for` loop in cases like this?

Comment: Well its your choice whether to use `for loop` or `map` whichever you feel comfortable with. but here is an article which explains advantages of using a map https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-stop-writing-loops-start-thinking-with-maps/

Comment: And another question, are those curly braces inside `.result` div for reading javascript code?

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No Problem glad to help

Comment: I noticed something, when I delete all the items, there's a blank `<h1></h1>` shown in the devtools.

Comment: YEs thats because you are wrapping the map within the <h1> tags and hence if map has not data nothing gets rendered into the h1 tags

Answer (score 1):

Your Mistake is , in loop you are assigning last value to `resultItem`. You need to push  data to  resultItem using array `push()` method. Everything else seems good. Better way is to use `.map()` instead of `for loop`

```
resultItem = [];

for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
   resultItem = results[i];//You are assigning resultItem only last value
}
```

Should Be:

```
resultItem = [];

for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {

 resultItem.push(<h1 key={i}>{results[i]}</h1>);
}
```

USING **.map()** Method:

```
   <div className='result'>
      {this.state.result.length>0 && this.state.result.map(function(item , index){
       return <h1 key={index}>{item}</h1>
      })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your for loop. It should be:

```
for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
      resultItem.push(results[i]);
    }
```

or if you want to create a separate tag for each item, you can do:

```
const list = resultItems.map((item) => <p>{item}</p>)
```

**Note:**

May be you can create a listitems. You should not have multiple h1. Also, comments does not work in the render section. So you should remove that.

Comment: You missed return statement in your .map method

Comment: There is no need to use return here. It will work this way

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
class Items extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          result: ''
        }
    
        this.showItems = this.showItems.bind(this);
      }

      showItems(e) {
         const items = e.target.value;
         this.setState({result: items});
      }
    
      renderValues(){
         let data = this.state.result;
         return data.split(' ').map((el, i) => <h1 key={i}>{el}</h1>)
      }
    
      render() {
    
        return(
          <div>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Enter items' onChange={this.showItems} />
    
            <div className='result'>

              {this.renderValues()}

            </div>
    
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

ReactDOM.render(<Items/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things in your code are problematic.

1. You're reassigning `resultItem` every time in the `for` loop. See:

   `resultItem = results[i];`

After the `for` loop ends, `resultItem` will only contain the last element of `results`.

2. You're rendering an array of strings directly within a `<h1>` element. See:

   `<h1>{resultItem}</h1>`

React *can* understand what to do with arrays, but it'll only render the items one after the other. You should include the `h1` tags within the array themselves. Idiomatic way to do it is to use `Array#map`:

```
// ...
{
  resultItem.map(str => <h1>str</h1>)
}
// ...
```

By the way, your `resultItem` variable looks extraneous. Just render `results` instead, you're basically just making a copy of it for `resultItem` anyway.